# Python Scipy Spectrogram

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, spectrogram

I am trying to plot the spectrograms of some .wav files.

I originally implemented it in Matlab, and my plot makes sense.

Matlab code:

```
sound = audioread(x); 
[S, F, T] = spectrogram(sound(:,1),1000,500,1000,48000); %get channel 1
S_dB = mag2db(abs(S));
%disp(S_dB)


%play sound
[y, fs] = audioread(x);
player = audioplayer(y, fs);
play(player);

%plot figure
figure;
imagesc(T, F, S_dB);
axis xy;
title(x,'Spectrogram');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)');
colorbar;
```

Matlab plot:
[image: matlab spectrogram plot]

I am trying to move my code over to Python, so I am using scipy. I have the following:

```
    rate, data = wavfile.read(file)
    #from Matlab: spectrogram(X = sound(:,1), WINDOW = 1000, NOVERLAP = 500,F = 1000,Fs = 48000)
    f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(data, fs=48000, window=('hamming'), nperseg=1000, noverlap=500, nfft=1000, detrend = 'constant', return_onesided=True, scaling='density', axis=-1, mode='psd')
    dB = control.mag2db(np.abs(Sxx)) #get magnitude of signal and convert to dB
    plt.pcolormesh(t, f, dB, shading='gouraud')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title(file) #V up, V down, H up, H down
    plt.show()
```

When I plot it in Python, I get this: [image: Python Spectrogram plot]

I took these recordings on a recorder with a relative max dB at -0 dB, so I know the Matlab file is right. I am not sure how to fix it in the Python file.

The S that is returned from the spectrogram file in Matlab is made up of complex numbers, and the Sxx that is returned in Python are real numbers (that differ from the real parts of the Matlab numbers). I am not sure why these numbers are so different? Any advice helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you set `mode='psd'` then `scipy.signal.spectrogram` returns the square of the magnitude. Thus `Sxx` should correspond to `abs(S)` squared.

Comment: That makes sense. I played around with the different types of modes, but I am pretty sure the Matlab spectrogram function defaults to PSD, so not sure why this is happening.  I tried changing the Python code to 'magnitude' mode and just returning the mag2dB() of that, but it still gives me answers above 0dB, which doesn't make sense to me if that is the maximum